# Schedule an action callback

Tags: cron, scheduled-posts

I have a function in which I want to send out emails of expiring account.  Is there a way of scheduling a "doaction()" or similar.  What I want is this:

```
 doaction('Something here', CheckMembershipRecords())
 function CheckMembershipRecords()
    {
    .... run through database and send emails.  
    }
```

It is the scheduling concept that I am not sure about or what even to call in the first parameter of the doaction call.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [`wp_schedule_event`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event) which hooks into the WordPress cron. Cron's job is to run tasks periodically from the back end.

Comment: Got it.  Thanks for the direction pointer...